# Starting syslog-ng

Tags: fedora, syslog-ng

I've recently installed syslog-ng but am confused about how to start it (on Fedora).

I do:

```
/etc/init.d/syslog-ng start
```

which reports that it's started ok. However, it doesn't actually do anything until I do:

```
/sbin/syslog-ng
```

at which point it starts behaving as I'd expect. Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Recent Fedora versions ship with `systemd`. There you could change to `syslog-ng` using the following commands:

```
yum install syslog-ng
systemctl disable rsyslog.service 
systemctl enable syslog-ng.service
systemctl stop rsyslog.service
systemctl start syslog-ng.service
```

At the end probably also remove `rsyslog` with `rpm -e rsyslog`.

Comment: Does `/etc/init.d/syslog-ng` exist regardless of `syslog-ng` being installed or not on Fedora? And it starts the default logger daemon, regardless of script's name?